# jquery validations are not working in asp.net when i use master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

jquery validations are not working when i use master page 
and i wrote code like

```
<script src="../script/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../script/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../script/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/jscript">
         $(document).ready(function() {

         $("#aspnetForm").validate({
                 rules: {
                ctl00$tcAccounts$tpnlChangePassword$tbEmployeeName: {
                         required: true
                     },
                     ctl00$tcAccounts$tpnlChangePassword$tbEmployeeMailId: {
                         required: true
                     }
                 },
                 messages: {
                 ctl00$tcAccounts$tpnlChangePassword$tbEmployeeName: {
                         required: "specify email"
                     },
                     ctl00$tcAccounts$tpnlChangePassword$tbEmployeeMailId: {
                         required: "specify password"
                     }
                 }
             });

         });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#aspnetForm").validate({
    rules: {
        <%= tbEmployeeName.UniqueID %>: {
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

Also Check this link

[Demo Link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-access-content-page-control-from-Master-Page-using-JavaScript-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Well, just as an idea. I can see that you're using ASP.NET TextBox. If it's in ASP.NET 4.5, why don't u use input with runat=server? In this case you will be able to use original element id instead of generated by ASP.NET.